# tex4ht and texMemo.cls

Tags: tex4ht

Running `tex4ht` on the example files that use the `texMemo` class

http://www.oak-tree.us/2010/08/02/texmemo/

give the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No \gdef \GenericError { }{LaTeX Error: No \gdef \GenericError {
               }{LaTeX Error: No \title given in `'}
```

I assume it's a problem with the way the class is set up. What should I look for to fix it?

Comment: try to use `\makememotitle` instead of `\maketitle`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not fix the problem. The error is the same.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd want to run `tex4ht` on a memo!